# this is be determined by... -- use of "be"?

Tags: grammaticality

Source: [UNIX System Administration—A Beginner's Guide by Steve Maxwell (2002)](https://books.google.com/books/about/UNIX_System_Administration_A_Beginner_s.html?id=tIAhAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)

Example:

> We would like to define this partition for the purposes of creating a new
>   file system. Also, notice that approximately 4 GB of storage is available for this new partition. **This is be determined** by examining the total amount of space reported with the backup partition (2) and comparing this information with the existing partition’s total disk space sizes.

I'm not sure how to understand that. What's specifically strange to me is how *be* is used there. Looks suspiciously like a subjunctive, but I'm not entirely sure, to tell you the truth. Would you agree that *this is determined* without *be* would sound equally fine?

Comment: It's not grammatical: I take it it's a mistake - perhaps the writers were undecided between "is" and "can be".

Comment: This looks like an editing typo. I think they probably decided to change it from *can be*  to *is* and forgot to remove the *to*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This is be determined" is wrong! The infinitive "be" is NEVER used with "is".

Alternatives are:
  This is determined
  This can be determined

Other modal verbs ('must', 'may', 'shall', along with the other forms 'might',  'could', 'should') are grammatical here in place of the 'is', but don't make much sense in the context.

By the way, this answer refers to 'standard English'. There may well be variants of English where "is be" is acceptable, but I don't know of any.

Comment: I doubt that McGraw-Hill would approve of non-standard English.